# How to access the Dark Arisen expansion content

Tags: dragons-dogma-dark-arisen

I just got the Dark Arisen expansion, but I can't figure out how to access the new content. I know that you're supposed to go to talk to a woman in Cassardis at night, but she doesn't seem to be there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about talking to a woman at Cassardis at night.

After sunset, if you go to the beach (the right hand side of pier, facing the sea) a short cut scene will trigger. However, the woman is **NOT** at the beach; she actually stands on the pier instead.